# Calculate percentage based on values corresponding to header name in separate table (R)

Tags: r, percentage

I'm attempting to calculate percentages from a table laid out like:

```
Thing    stuff    group1    group2    group3
Abcd     A.       42.       17.       0
Y682.    B.       3.        12.       9
Bh57.    A.       22.       10.       1
Jdje.    B.       2.        3.        12
```

(Pardon the formatting and errant periods, I'm submitting from my phone.)

I have a corresponding table that has the number that the values need to be divided by based on their column name.

```
Group1.   45
Group2.   30
Group3.   15
```

With the desired output being:

```
Thing    stuff    group1    group2    group3
Abcd     A.       93.3      56.7      0
Y682.    B.       6.7       40.0      60.0
Bh57.    A.       48.9      33.3      6.66
Jdje.    B.       4.4       10.0      80
```

I haven't sat down to work on this yet, just hoping to get a jump start on it for tomorrow!  Thanks for any help.

EDIT:SOLUTION
I was able to get it working by using:

```
df3 <- df1 
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df2))) 
{ 
df3[, df2$Type[i]] <- format((df1[, df2$Type[i]] / df2$n[i])*100,digits=2) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that works, though it's not necessarily scale able for larger datasets:

```
 df <- data.frame(Thing=c("Abcd", "Y682", "BH", "Jd"), 
                  stuff=c("A","B","A","B"),
                  G1=c(42,3,22,2),
                  G2=c(17,12,10,3),
                  G3=c(0,9,1,12))

 df2 <- data.frame(G1=45, G2=30, G3=15)

 for(i in 3:ncol(df)){
    df[, i] <- df[, i]/df2[, i-2]*100
 }
```

This relies on the columns being in the right order in the second dataframe

EDIT: this is a better way that doesn't rely on columns being in the right order, but you do still need the column names to match between data frames:

```
 for (i in names(df)){
   if (exists(where = df2, x = i)){
     df[, i] <- format(as.numeric(df[, i])/df2[, which(names(df2)==i)], digits=2)
   }
 }
```

Comment: You could then use `format(df[, i]/df2[, i-2]*100, digits=1)` to get the right number of digits

Comment: You'd need digits=2 for that to look the same as OPs

Comment: Thanks for the response!    
Running it as is with my data doesn't produce a result. It seems to be not finding any matches.    

my df2 is set up with one column of names, and a second column of numbers, so I have attempted to create a transposed version to work with this by using:  
    `df2_t <- spread(df2, Type, n)`  

But that results in the following error:  
    `Error in format(as.numeric(df[, i])/df2_t[, which(names(df2_t) ==  :(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

Comment: I'm still struggling at this. I have a large data set, and the data is stored as a data frame. It looks like the only way to get this to work is by converting my datasets to matrix's. But then all I get is a "NULL" for i.

Comment: can you edit your questions to include your actual data? Use `dput(data)` and paste in the output for both df and df2 then I can help more easily

Comment: But as it stands, the column names of df2 are not the same as df1 so my way wouldn't work. I'd recommend changing the column names to match

Comment: I was able to get it working by using:  `df3 <- df1
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df2)))
{
  df3[, df2$Type[i]] <- format((df1[, df2$Type[i]] / df2$n[i])*100,digits=2)
}`